# Scrapy-Splash Requested URL vs Real URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to make instantaneous reports for some of my webpages using the Splash and Scrapy-Splash python module.

The problem is that I can't obtain the corect last url like in splash render.json. When a website redirects.
For example on localhost:8050/render.json the result for rendering www.google.com is:

```
{"requestedUrl": "http://www.google.com/", 
"url": "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl", 
"title": "Google", "geometry": [0, 0, 1024, 768]}
```

But inside my python script I only manage to obtain **"http://www.google.com"**

My code is:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        splash_args = { 'wait': 1 }
        return SplashRequest(
            response.url,
            self.parse_link,
            args=splash_args,
            endpoint='render.json',
            ) 

    def parse_link(self, response):
        result = {
            'requested_url': response.data['requestedUrl'],
            'real_url': response.data['url'],
            'response': response.request.url,
            'splash_url': response.real_url
            }
```

But any of this returns:

```
{"requested_url": "http://www.google.com/", 
 "real_url": "http://www.google.com/", 
 "response": "http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json", 
 "splash_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json"}
```

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Are you running your spider with a custom user agent? When I use the default (USER_AGENT commented out in settings.py), or a made up user agent, I also get what you posted. When I specify a real user agent I get the value you are expecting. It seems like Google does some validation on the user agent and returns a different response. Splash UI sends a proper user agent (from your actual browser).

Comment: No I use the standard "Chrome agent" - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36"

But anyway I renounce using scrapy and now I'm using pyppeeter.... 
And instead of HAR I'll only record the requests...